# uib-popover not disappearing when used with uib-datepicker-popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using a uib-datepicker-popup with a uib-popover triggered by "mouseenter". The popover appears just fine when I mouse over the datepicker element. But if I select a date, the popover remains visible until I mouse over the datepicker element again.

```
<p uib-popover="I won't go away" popover-trigger="'mouseenter'">
      <input uib-datepicker-popup is-open="popup.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-model="dt" close-text="Close" type="text"/>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" ng-click="open()"><i class="icon"></i></button>
      </span>
</p>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VEwjPT?p=preview)

I've made a [ticket](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/6513) for this but since I'm not sure if it's a bug or if I'm just missing something with a configuration change, I'm asking here too.

How can I get the popover to disappear again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it might be a bug, you can still work around that by setting the popover on the input not the calendar button as follows

```
<input
  type="text"
  uib-popover="I won't go away"
  popover-trigger="'mouseenter'"
  popup-placement="bottom-right"
  class="form-control"
  uib-datepicker-popup
  ng-model="dt"
  is-open="popup2.opened"
  datepicker-options="dateOptions"
  ng-required="true"
  close-text="Close" />
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/B3gz63?p=preview)